# How to properly factorize expression with respect to specific combinations of terms?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, factorization

This is something that I have never been able to properly do in Mathematica so I wish to learn how to do it once and for all.

I have the following expression in Mathematica:

```
A=-(1/(12 h)) m (-24 ql qr + (768 ql (ql + qr))/(8 + h ω^2) + (
768 qr (ql + qr))/(8 + h ω^2) + 
ql^2 (-84 + h^2 ω^2) + qr^2 (-84 + h^2 ω^2) + (
64 (ql + qr)^2 (-48 + h^2 ω^2))/(8 + h ω^2)^2)
```

(or in traditional form)

$$
A=-\frac{m \left(\frac{64 \left(h^2 \omega ^2-48\right) \left(q_l+q_r\right){}^2}{\left(h \omega ^2+8\right)^2}+\left(h^2 \omega ^2-84\right) q_l^2+\left(h^2 \omega ^2-84\right) q_r^2+\frac{768 q_l \left(q_l+q_r\right)}{h \omega ^2+8}+\frac{768 q_r \left(q_l+q_r\right)}{h \omega ^2+8}-24 q_l q_r\right)}{12 h}
$$

where $h,\omega>0$ and $m\ge 0$. I would like to reorganize A so as to obtain B:

$$
B=\frac{1}{12} h m \omega ^2 \left(\frac{h^2 \omega ^2}{16}+1\right) q_l q_r-h m \omega ^2 \left(\frac{h^4 \omega ^4}{768}-\frac{5 h^2 \omega ^2}{128}+\frac{7}{24}\right) \left(q_l^2+q_r^2\right)+\frac{m \left(q_r-q_l\right){}^2}{2 h}
$$

What is the proper strategy to take the form A to the form B?

Comment: My best attempt so far is: `res = (FactorSquareFree /@ Apart@A) // Collect[#, {m, (ql + qr)}] &`

Comment: Do you mean $B$ to appear naturally, or after you specify some or all the factors or terms ? If You mean $B$ to appear naturally, without specific inputs.; Which features define $B$ the way you like it?

Comment: @rhermans I do not wish for B to appear naturally, but maybe just by specifying that I want to factorize terms with respect to $m(q_r-q_l)^2$, $hm\omega^2(q_l^2+q_r^2)$ and $hm\omega^2 q_l q_r$